# Postfix Header_Check Regex 'Does Not Match' issue

Tags: postfix, regex

I am trying to configure Postfix to NOT accept outbound messages with FROM addresses other than my own domains.

The following regex successfully rejects only 3 domains:

```
/etc/postfix/header_checks:
/(^From:.*domain\.com|^From:.*domain\.net|^From:.*domain\.co\.il)/ REJECT SEND FROM THE RIGHT DOMAINS FFS!
```

I'd like to basically reverse it and block EVERYTHING BUT those 3.

So according to the manual:

> !/pattern/flags result
>                 When  pattern  does  not  match the input string, use the corre-
>                 sponding result value.

However, this just blocks everything:

```
/etc/postfix/header_checks:
!/(^From:.*domain\.com|^From:.*domain\.net|^From:.*domain\.co\.il)/ REJECT SEND FROM THE RIGHT DOMAINS FFS!
```

Comment: Meh, even after creating such a beautifully crafted regex that finds everything but them domains it wont accept it: 
^(?!(From:.*domain.net|From:.*domain.com|From:.*domain.co.il)).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is postfix use header_checks for **every** header line. So if there is header line like

```
Subject: I love you :p
```

and postfix will apply that regex into this line. The result is postfix will reject this email.

The solution is adding `if endif` in your regex pattern

```
if /^From:/
!/(^From:.*domain\.com|^From:.*domain\.net|^From:.*domain\.co\.il)/ REJECT SEND FROM THE RIGHT DOMAINS FFS!
endif
```

Basically you tell postfix to apply the pattern into *From* header only. This will prevent postfix to evaluate the regex into another header line and causes rejected email.

See [postfix manual](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) 
to further information

Comment: You sir deserve a medal!